# Why does MOI of rectangle depend on length of diagonal of the rectangle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

If we have a rectangle of length $a$ and width $b$

[image: Picture]

my physics textbook showed that the MOI about the axis of rotation in the picture is given by
\begin{align}\label{MOI rectangle}
\dfrac{1}{12}M(a^2+b^2)
\end{align}
However, $a^2+b^2$ is the [squared] length of the diagonal of the rectangle. Why is the MOI about the center of the rectangle proportional to it's diagonal? Is there any way to derive the rotational inertia of the rectangle using the diagonal length (as opposed to the sum of rods as in the figure)?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?   MOI of an object goes up as you put more mass farther away from the axis.   The longer the diagonal, the farther away some of the mass is from the axis.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I'm looking for an intuitive answer, or perhaps a derivation of the same result using the length of the diagonal. Also, in your explanation, I don't get what is so special about the diagonal, verses say the edges of the rectangle.